# Java String contains extraneous data

Tags: java, string, parsing, encoding, numbers

I have an input which is in UTF16LE encoding. By the time this input reaches my code its been through a FileInputStream encased in a FileReader encased in a LineNumberReader.

The first line read gives a string like:

`"1 piece of data like a string"`

However, looking into this String the value will be something along the lines of:

```
[, 1, p, i, ...]
```

Notice the empty element to start.

No this string is passed through a couple of functions here and there, converted to Object and basically is being put through its paces. At a certain point, what should only be the first part of the String (the 1 or in my case any number including with decimals) is passed to a function which has to parse it to an actual Number.

The content of this String appears to be `"1"` but in the value it says:

```
[, 1, p, i, ...]
```

so the whole string is still in there.

In any case it returns a `ParseException` and I print the unparseable number to an exception  messages and my logging tels me that "1" is an unparseable number.

The real problem appears to be the leading empty element as subsequent lines show similar behavior except for the leading empty element and they parse.

Comment: "However, looking into this String the value will be something along the lines of: [, 1, p, i, ...]". That does not make sense. How did you identify the elements of the String? A Java string is a sequence of `char`s, and there's no such thing as an "empty char". What exactly did you see when debugging?

Comment: As sleske suggests, the "empty" element is not really empty. You should print out its numerical value to see what code point it is. My guess is that it could have something to do with the BOM...

Comment: This could be a BOM (I should've added that to my story) but UTF16LE is not allowed to have a BOM because the LE already says that. Even so, the parser encoding is explicitly set to UTF16LE.

I identified the contents of the string via the eclipse debugger and what I wrote is what eclipse says is the content.

Comment: One way of debugging this is to iterate over the String, using String.getChar(index) to fetch individual `char`s. Then print each `char` using String.((int)c) . The cast to int will give you the numeric value of the char (i.e. the Unicode code point).

Comment: @Jasper: And never blindly believe the debugger :-).

Comment: @sleske: you can believe the debugger, but you must know how to interpret what it tells you ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone for you answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the answer. The encoding was not UTF16LE. It was set to UTF16LE by an auto char detection algorithm. The encoding is utf16 with a BOM. However since the various classes thought the encoding was UTF16LE they were not getting rid of the BOM which shouldn't be there in the LE version.

Comment: btw gvim also identifies the file as UTF16LE which it isnt.  I didn't create the source file, nor can I expect to outside of testing environments, I am forced to guess the encoding more often than not.

Answer (score 2):

A `String` (at least the implementation in the OpenJDK) stores a `char[]`, an offset and a count. The actual content of the `String` are the characters in the `char[]` with the indices `offset` up to `offset+count`.

That means that the `char[]` can hold more characters than the `String` actually represents.

This is done in order to be able to share `char[]`s between different `String` instances.

For example, if you have a `String` with the value `foobar` and you call `.substring(3)` on it, then the resulting `String` will represent `bar`, but they may actually reference the same `char[]`. The second `String` will just have an `offset` that 3 bigger than the originals `String` and a `count` that's 3 smaller.

All of this only works because `String` objects are truly immutable: since no single `String` will ever modify it's `char[]` in any way, it's perfectly safe for them to share it.

This means that inspecting a `String` object in the debugger might give a false impression. Therefore the safest thing to do if you want to inspect a `String` character-for-character is to call either [`toCharArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) or to call [`charAt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) in a loop.

Comment: Thanks, very clear. It is unfortunate that this means adding debug code which the debugger is supposed to replace. That is just how it goes.

Comment: @Jasper: well, the `String` display shows the correct and exact value 99% of the time (i.e. each time the `String` contains only printable characters). And the other time you should be able to execute small code pieces directly in your debugger of choice: no need to add them to your production code.